# How to find xpath of an element in a window that's inside another "frame window"

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to find the xpath of an element located in a window that's opened in another window for use in a python script for selenium.

The page is essentially a frame which hosts another page inside (think browser within a browser window).

I can find the xpath of the window itself that's inside the outside browser window, but I can't seem to use xpath to select any of the elements on the inner window.

This is the overall xpath to select the element I want.

`/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span/iframe/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a[1]`

The xpath to select the inner window is:

`/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span/iframe`

The xpath to select the item inside the inner window (if directly on inner window's page) is:

`/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a[1]`

I've tried using all these methods, but haven't been able to select elements on the inner page.

Here is the Python code:

```
    survivorFrame = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='theSurvivorIframe']")[0]
    driver.switch_to_frame(survivorFrame)
    elem1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='lea1_ileinner']/a[1]")
    survivorOwner = re.search('>(.*)<', elem1)
    print elem1
    print survivorOwner
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to switch control to inside the iframe and then try and interact with the webelement

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0] 
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

and to come out of the iframe back to the main window

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: This sort of works.  After trying to select an element in the iframe after switching to it, the element just appears as `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x108900b50>]`

Comment: What do you expect "survivorOwner = re.search('>(.*)<', elem1)" this to do?

Comment: I got it to work!  It was showing up as a list because I had elements instead of element.  Thank you so much for your help!  You saved me hours of aggravation!

Comment: I was going to have it search for elem1's text, but just using elem1.text worked after I took the s out of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('yourframeid'));
```

where the `yourframeid` is the ID for your frame or iframe